# Should I use loaders populate my spinners from my database?

Tags: android, performance

I want to load my spinners with strings 1776-to-1865. I stored all of these values in a year column in my DB coupled with a content provider.

### Rephrasing:

He wants to load the spinner values obtained by a content provider & the content provider uses a db to source the values.

Now he is asking whether he should use a "loading" type thing while he is populating the spinner.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Improve it to get a clear and quick answer.

Comment: What else should I add to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#app

Scroll down to "Using Loaders in an Application"

If your app meets all or most of these criteria, use a loader:

- An Activity or Fragment.
- An instance of the LoaderManager.
- A CursorLoader to load data backed by a ContentProvider. Alternatively, you    can implement your own subclass of Loader or AsyncTaskLoader to load data from some other source.
- An implementation for LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks. This is where you create new loaders and manage your references to existing loaders.
- A way of displaying the loader's data, such as a SimpleCursorAdapter.
- A data source, such as a ContentProvider, when using a CursorLoader.

Comment: Please refer to the question instead of only citing the Android documentation.

Answer (score 1):

you should use loaders. As accessing from DB is relatively a slower performing task.

Comment: its not about the 90 rows. on general notes, its always slower if we are accessing a single row in terms of standard execution time. And as he didn't mention, number of rows could be increased in future & generally it does grow. Considering these all things, I suggested to use loaders.

Comment: and when trying to insert/update/delete you also are using hmm.. loaders?

Comment: if these were affecting my UI then yes I would prefer to be on the safe side. But really depends on the situation. To me this question & it's answer is more subjective than objective.

Comment: what does it mean "safe side", if a db operation takes 20-30 ms does it really pays off to spawn another background thread? did you try to measure how much those "relatively a slower performing task" operations take time?

Comment: as we understood from community editing of the question, by "loader" he meant "loading" type messages / icons etc. not the traditional "loader" threads. And again, I would say it really depends on the scenario whether we should use background threads or not.

Comment: @pskink 20-30ms is way to much to do in the UI thread. As we know 16ms are the way to go